# Delete photos JUST from iPhone and not Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac, photos, macos

How can I delete photos just from my iPhone and not in my photo library from the Mac?

Every time I delete photos from my iPhone it'll be deleted on my Mac and vice versa...

Thank you